# How to bind keys, in my program Calculator. Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I want to bind a key for my calculator. I would like to connect the keys
with a keyboard in the calculator. But I can't.

As I was looking on the internet, it was all done at Claas. Do I have to rewrite the entire program? Thank you for every answer. I am new so forgive me for mistakes.

```
from tkinter import *
wyrazenie = "
#num
def press(num):
    global wyrazenie
    wyrazenie = wyrazenie + str(num)
    equation.set(wyrazenie)
    #equalpress
def equalpress():
    try:
        global wyrazenie
        total = str(eval(wyrazenie))
        equation.set(total)
        wyrazenie = ""
    except:
        equation.set(" błąd ")
        wyrazenie = ""
#clear
def clear():
    global wyrazenie
    wyrazenie = ""
    equation.set("")
#app
if __name__ == "__main__":
    okno = Tk()
#okno
    okno.configure(background='snow3')
    topFrame = Frame(okno)
    topFrame.grid()
    bottomFrame = Frame(okno)
    bottomFrame.grid()
    okno.title("Kalkulator")
    equation = StringVar()
    wyrazenie_pole = Entry(okno, textvariable=equation)
    wyrazenie_pole.grid(columnspan=4, ipadx=60)

    equation.set('')

#keys
    color_bg = 'deep sky blue' #kolor przycisków
    color_fg = ""
    button1 = Button(okno, text=' 1 ', fg='black', bg=color_bg,
                     command=lambda: press(1), height=1, width=7)
    button1.grid(row=3, column=0)
    if okno.bind('<Button-1>'):

    button2 = Button(okno, text=' 2 ', fg='black', bg=color_bg,
                     command=lambda: press(2), height=1, width=7)
    button2.grid(row=3, column=1)

    button3 = Button(okno, text=' 3 ', fg='black', bg=color_bg,
                     command=lambda: press(3), height=1, width=7)
    button3.grid(row=3, column=2)

    plus = Button(okno, text=' + ', fg='black', bg=color_bg,
                  command=lambda: press("+"), height=1, width=7)
    plus.grid(row=3, column=3)

    minus = Button(okno, text=' - ', fg='black', bg=color_bg,
                   command=lambda: press("-"), height=1, width=7)
    minus.grid(row=4, column=3)

    clear = Button(okno, text='Clear', fg='black', bg=color_bg,
                   command=clear, height=1, width=7)
    clear.grid(row=7, column='1')

    okno.mainloop()
```

Comment: Do you get error message ? always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (as text, not screenshot). There are other useful information. (PL: jeśli dostajesz komunikat o błędzie to zawsze pokazuj cały komunikat)

Comment: do you mean you want to press keys on keyboard instead of pressing buttons on screen ?

Comment: `okno.bind("+", lambda event:press("+"))`. `bind` executes function with one parameter (`event`) so `lambda` has to get this parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def press(num):
    global wyrazenie
    # wyrazenie = wyrazenie + str(num)
    wyrazenie = equation.get() + str(num) # get current text and add last sign pressed
    equation.set(wyrazenie)
    wyrazenie_pole.icursor(len(wyrazenie)) # set cursor at the end
```

also you can set focus on your Entry:

```
wyrazenie_pole = Entry(okno, textvariable=equation)
wyrazenie_pole.grid(columnspan=4, ipadx=60)
wyrazenie_pole.focus()
```